# Laravel 8: Trying to get property 'price' of non-object

Tags: php, laravel, cart, laravel-8

I'm trying to make an online store with Laravel 8 and for my `cart.blade.php` I coded this:

```
<div class="text-right mt-4">
    <label class="text-muted font-weight-normal m-0">Final Price</label>

    @php
        $totalPrice = Cart::all()->sum(function($cart) {
        return $cart['product']->price * $cart['quantity'];
        });
    @endphp
    <div class="text-large"><strong>{{ $totalPrice }} is price</strong></div>
</div>
```

And method `all()` goes like this:

```
public function all()
    {
        $cart = $this->cart;
        $cart = $cart->map(function($item) {
            return $this->withRelationshipIfExist($item);
        });

        return $cart;
    }
```

So how to fix this issue? I would really appreciate any idea or suggestion from you guys...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `dd($cart)` to check what's inside the variable.

Comment: It's not a good idea, to make your query on blade template

Comment: you are calling all method like it is static, but its not

Comment: Which cart package are you using? There may be an easier way to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is telling you that $cart is not an object.  This happens when it is not being set correctly.

If your all() function is in your Cart model, then you actually don't want $this->cart.  You would simply want $cart = $this.